# Restrict Login with Google OAuth2.0 and Devise to Specific Whitelist Table using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

So I was trying to use omniauth2 to check if the email had the right @domain.com but I think using a database table will allow more functionality as well as being more secure and such.

My previous question: [Restrict Login with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Whitelisted Domain Name on Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294102/restrict-login-with-google-oauth2-0-to-specific-whitelisted-domain-name-on-ruby/23294707#23294707)

I think I want to use a database table to check the email that google authenticated against a whitelist of emails, is there anyway to do this with devise and omniauth2? That way I can say only certain users are authorized after they get authenticated with Google. I have most info listed on my previous question but if there is some more info I can give let me know.
Thanks.

EDIT: Not sure how much this helps but here is a question similar; however, I am still using google and omniauth [Whitelisting with devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167576/whitelisting-with-devise)

EDIT: I think the above "Whitelisting with devise" is pretty close to the answer, but there are still a few kinks to work out. I'm not sure how to start implementing everything I'm pretty new to ruby in particular.

Here is my route:

```
   devise_for :user, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "user/omniauth_callbacks" }
And that controller:

    class User::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      def google_oauth2
      @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
        if @user.persisted?
          flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        else
          session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    end
```

If I understand the Whitelisting with devise correctly I have to create another controller in between and use that to check the email? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my user.rb I think this might hold the answer possibly?:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :provider, :uid, :avatar

def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

    unless user
        user = User.create(name: data["name"],
             email: data["email"],
             password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            )
    end
    user
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a validation to the User Model so, no user would be created if the email that comes from oauth is not form a certain domain:

```
validates :email,
           presence: true,
           uniqueness: true,
           format: {
                   message: 'domain must be example.com',
                   with: /\A[\w+-.]+@example.com\z/i
                   }
```