# Limiting OAuth login to a specific email domain

Tags: google-oauth

I am using the Google PHP API to authenticate user login. I would like to restrict login access to specific email domains, eg only users with email @thedomain.com can login.

I've tried setting the [hd parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858813/restrict-login-email-with-google-oauth2-0-to-specific-domain-name) as suggested, with no luck. I also noticed that the returned `$client = new Google_Client();` object returns an empty string for `["hd"]=> string(0) ""`

Checking the [email domain after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235590/how-do-you-restrict-google-login-oauth2-to-emails-from-a-specific-google-apps) may be viable, but i fell like there must be a method within the Google API.

Anyone have ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the `hd` object, which required instantiating a new `$service`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        // create service to pull userinfo
        $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $user = $service->userinfo->get();
        $userHd = $user['hd'];
        if ($userHd === 'thedomain.com') {
            // log the user in
        }
```